# php regular expression issue

Tags: php, regex

yes, I know that using regular expressions on html is not preferred, but I am still confused as to why this doesn't work:

I'm trying to remove the "head" from a document.
Here's the doc:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <!--
     a comment within the head
     -->
 </head>
 <body>
stuff in the body
 </body>
</html>
```

My code:

```
$matches = array(); $result = preg_match ('/(?:<head[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/head>)/is', $contents, $matches); 
var_dump ($matches);
```

This does not actually work.
Here's the output I see:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(60) " " [1]=> string(47) " " [2]=> string(7) "" }
```

However, if I adjust the HTMl doc to not have the comment

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to remove the head of the document? I can't think of any reason why you would want to.

Comment: Long story, but mostly playing around with a script that is parsing the body only.  I recognize this isn't the best way to go about it, but wanted to still debug my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working fine, it's not displaying correctly due to the HTML in the dump (you can tell by the lengths in your `var_dump` output).  Try:

```
$result = preg_match ('/(?:<head[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/head>)/is', $contents, $matches); 
ob_start(); // Capture the result of var_dump
var_dump ($matches);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean()); // Escape HTML in the dump
```

Also, as has been said, you need to use `preg_replace` to replace the match with `''` in order to actually  remove the head.

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression looks fine, but that *extracts* the `<head>`; you want to *remove* the head. Try using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead:

```
$without_head = preg_replace ('/(?:<head[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/head>)/is', '', $contents);
```

Comment: I was using preg_replace to remove it, but was having so much trouble figuring why it wasn't working.  I switched to preg_replace for debugging.  I also just updated the question with the output I'm seeing

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $str=<<<EOS
<<< > <head>
<<< >    <!--
<<< >      a comment within the head
<<< >      -->
<<< >  </head>
<<< > EOS;
php > $r=preg_match('/(?:<head[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/head>)/is',$str,$matches);
php > var_dump($r);
int(1)
php > var_dump($matches);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(63) "<head>
   <!--
     a comment within the head
     -->
 </head>"
  [1]=>
  string(50) "
   <!--
     a comment within the head
     -->
 "
  [2]=>
  string(7) "</head>"
}
```

Do you mean to use preg_replace?

```
php > $r=preg_replace('/(?:<head[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/head>)/is','',$str);
php > var_dump($r);
string(0) ""
```